# Probability distribution arising from the combination of a normal variable and an other random variable

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, independence

Let $X\backsim N(0,5^2)$ and Y be an independent random variable taking the values +1 and -1 with equal probability.Find the distribution of $S=XY+\frac{X}{Y}, T=XY-\frac{X}{Y}$

I have solved the first part in the following way,but unable to find the distribution of $T$

We can write,$F(S)=P[S\leq s|Y=1].P[Y=1]+P[S\leq s|Y=-1].P[Y=-1]$

$=P[2X\leq s|Y=1].\frac{1}{2}+P[-2X\leq s|Y=-1].\frac{1}{2}$

$=\frac{1}{2}(P[X\leq\frac{s}{2}]+P[-X\leq\frac{s}{2}])$

As $X$ and $-X$ are both following $N(0,5^2)$ ,we can write $P[X\leq\frac{s}{2}]=\phi(\frac{s}{10})$
$\rightarrow S \backsim N(0,10^2)$

But in case of $T=XY-\frac{X}{Y}$, we see that $T=0$ when $Y=+1$ or $-1$

Can anyone tell me how to find the distribution of $T?$

Comment: This page gives some useful information about combining normal distributions using different operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Related_distributions. Also, for the more general case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Comment: 1. Is T ever anything *but* 0? .... 2. can you draw its cdf?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. $T=0$ always with probability $1.$ It has a degenerate distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution